# jQuery validation plug-in is failing element validations even when elements are disabled

Tags: jquery, validation

A sample of the HTML snippet is here:

```
<select name="paytitle" id="paytitle">
    <option value="Budget Keeper" selected>Budget Keeper</option>
    <option value="Bookkeeper">Bookkeeper</option>
    <option value="Treasurer">Treasurer</option>
    <option value="Accounts Payable">Accounts Payable</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="otherfield">Other: <input name="paytitleother" type="text" id="paytitleother" class="required" /></div>
```

I have a function that disables and hides the paytitleother field based on the select value:

```
$('#paytitle').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Other')
    {
        $("#paytitleother").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#otherfield").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $("#paytitleother").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#otherfield").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

When I attempt to submit the form, the paytitleother field is still failing validation even though it is disabled and hidden.  Documentation on the validation plug-in states all disabled fields are ignored automatically but I went the extra step to add `ignore: ":disabled"` to the validation routine:

```
$('#fieldForm').validate({
    ignore: ':disabled',
    ...
});
```

Even with this specification, the validation of the field fails. I have been working all day on this project so it's possible I'm overlooking something simple but I can't see it and can't fathom for the life of me what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the `disabled` attribute, trying using a value of "disabled" instead of `true`, like so:

```
$("#paytitleother").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on `.attr()` has some comments related to how set the "disabled" attribute in HTML 4 vs. XHTML and even some musings on HTML5.

Comment: thanks - I have read conflicting information on which method (true vs. "disabled") to use and I try to stay away from front-end development as much as possible - this in combination with realizing the designer had not preset the initial state of all the hidden elements to disabled to begin with fixed all of my issues